# MPAndroidChart, LineChart: How to implement part/portion selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I successfully implemented division grid lines and some other features as i required by tweaking [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.

What I'm trying to implement next is the selection pointers (Can be seen in RED COLOR in attached Image No. 1). Any kind of helping material such as code, doc or even a direction to implement such a thing will be appreciated.

On Side Note: There is an other issue. I'm always getting that white empty space between 12AM and yAxisRight labels. (Can be seen in attached Image No. 2)

Looking forward.

Image No. 1:: [image: Image No. 1]

Image No. 2:: [image: Image No. 2]

Comment: at least for your second problem i might can help you. Try to set the Maximum on the XAxis `chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(<12AM>);`

Comment: @woodii I'm already using xAxis.setAxisMaximum(24f);. See code below for xAxis.

XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
xAxis.setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrey80));
xAxis.setGridLineWidth(1f);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
xAxis.setTextSize(15f);
xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(24f);
xAxis.setLabelCount(25, true);

Comment: i know a labelCount of 25 should be correct in your case but have you tried playing around with that? Does the error still occurs if you remove this line?

Comment: A little silly of me, there was a function available 'setVisibleXRangeMinimum' to adjust maximum visible region of chart, that i didn't explore earlier.. Thanks for making me look into it again. :)

PS: Any hunch for my 1st issue?

Comment: take a look into https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting ... you can define your own `ChartHighlighter` ... maybe this can help?!?
but i think this feature is not implemented in the library yet so you have to do it your own ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function available in mpchart library 'setVisibleXRangeMinimum' to adjust maximum visible region of chart.